# Merging two individual rounded objects in illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The roof and the body of the house are individual objects that have individually been rounded. I want to combine these objects without affecting the rounding features already on each object.

[image: Desired outcome of house]

But when I try to use the Shape Builder Tool, it manipulates the rounding of the edges in a weird way. 
[image: Shape builder attempt]

I have tried many things with the shape builder tool (i.e. only highlighting certain parts of the shapes, holding shift), but I can't get it to just happily merge the two edited-shapes. I want to do this so when I add a gradient overlay, the overlay looks smooth and not like its affecting individual objects.

[image]

I am new to Illustrator, so this may trivial, but I appreciate any help anyone can give!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Select both objects and go to 'Object → Expand Appearance' before using the  shape builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can combined two shape of different radius with **Pathfinder**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's something you can improve in your workflow to avoid problems like this.

1. Create the triangle and the rectangle shape;[image]
2. Open Pathfinder from: Windows -> Pathfinder;[image]
3. Select the two shapes, in pathfinder panel, click "Unite";[image]
4. Switch to Direct Selection Tool (Shortcut is "A"), select the anchor points you want to get rounded, drag the handle; [image]*You can select multiple anchor points at the same time, so they can be rounded to the same level.*
5. After that, you can apple any effect to the combined shape.[image]

*Note this: Always hold down Shift key when you resizing this shape, or the corners will be flattened.*